# update a column of table in sql server from ms access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2007

I have a table in sql server, and another table in ms access. The two tables are different tables. but one column in sql server need fresh data from the table in ms access. Is that possible that when ms access have update or new record, the table in sql server will be updated automatically.

Comment: Why are you storing two copies of the same data? Why not just do everything in the sql server table and drop the access table completely?

Comment: We are two different organization.

Comment: So what? If the two tables need to be in sync there is no reason to store two copies of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely yes! Just link the [SQL Server table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-link-to-SQL-Server-data-a5a3b4eb-57b9-45a0-b732-77bc6089b84e) in Access via ODBC (after setting up a DSN). On ribbon, see External Data tab (ODBC).

Then, run an append and update query in the After Insert or After Update VBA trigger event on form from the local table into the linked table.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Any sample VBA trigger for after insert?

Comment: Simply, create the append and update Access queries. Then in the After Insert event, open the queries using the command: `DoCmd.OpenQuery "<NAME OF APPEND OR UPDATE QUERY>"`